# javascript template image

Tags: javascript, html, image, templates

I'm using a javascript template like this:

```
<script id="template" type='text/tmpl'>
  <img src="{{=imagesrc}}" />
</script>
```

The problem is that loading that template the page would try to make a request to `http://site.com/{{=imagesrc}}`.

My understanding was that using the script element type should prevent what's inside from being interpreted as html?

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: what templating system is that, is this jquery template?

Comment: @Amjad Masad nope, doT template

Comment: not fimiliar with it, but your right setting the `type` to something other than `text/javascript` prevents the browser from executing it as JS. I couldn't find any documentation on doT, if you could include a link to the docs ill be glad to try and help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're really trying to do.. but you could try wrapping whatever is inside your script tag with CDATA:

```
<script>
  /*<![CDATA[*/

    Your stuff here

  /*]]>*/
</script>
```